# Jupyter Notebook(Anaconda) and Python IDLE/Shell and Python on command prompt

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to know whether all these different and independent of each other? And what does pip list exactly show? Because in my pip list I can see that I have numpy 1.14.3 , and when I import it on command prompt or jupyter notebook, it is successfully importing, but when I tried importing it on Python Shell, it showed that no such module exists. I am using Windows 10. Python IDLE is version 3.6.
[image: This is my python version on command prompt and as there is Anaconda written beside it, maybe both are interlinked]

Recently, I installed OpenCV using this command-
pip install opencv-contrib-python

And after that I was able to import cv2 on command prompt but not on jupyter notebook and neither on Python Shell/IDLE

But when I installed tensorflow using-
pip install tensorflow
After that I was able to import tensorflow both on jupyter notebook and command prompt but not on IDLE.

I just wanted to know that how many Pythons do I have on my laptop and when I have to install a package which I do using pip, then what for am I exactly installing it, whether it is for Python Shell or command prompt or jupyter notebook. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you install Python in the first place? Did you install both Anaconda as well as from the official site? Also, if you installed via Anaconda then i'd suggest you use `conda` for listing and installing packages instead of `pip`.

Comment: Python I installed from the official Python site along with IDLE and Shell. Later in a workshop, they got me to install Anaconda. And I have no idea whether all these 3 Python are interrelated or not.

Comment: Please remove the image and copy that information directly. It isn't clear at all.

Comment: That can pose problems. Anaconda also installs Python. So now package managers are confused. Can you uninstall both and only install Anaconda?

Comment: Hello Raj. Thanks for replying. If I uninstall both and then again install Anaconda, then will I again have to download numpy and tensorflow? Or will it be better if I just uninstall Python IDLE as it doesn't even come in use much. I use Python on command prompt which is linked to Anaconda I think.